# How to use Swift in React Native Turbo Modules

Tags: swift, objective-c, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge, react-native-turbomodule

I followed the guide here to create a turbo module. This was fine.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-turbomodules

I want to use Swift code in this turbo module. I tried adding a Swift file with this code and modifying the `RTNCalculator.mm` so that the number addition happens in Swift called from Objective-C.

SwiftCalculator.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc class SwiftCalculator: NSObject {
    @objc func add(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

RTNCalculator.mm

```
#import "RTNCalculatorSpec.h"
#import "RTNCalculator.h"
#import "RTNCalculator-Swift.h"

@implementation RTNCalculator

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (void)add:(double)a b:(double)b resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject {
    SwiftCalculator *calculator = [SwiftCalculator new];
    double value = [calculator addWithA:a b:b];
    NSNumber *result = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:value];
    resolve(result);
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:
    (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
    return std::make_shared<facebook::react::NativeCalculatorSpecJSI>(params);
}

@end
```

I also modified the pod spec file to use a bridging header file.

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 
    'SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER' => '../../node_modules/rtn-calculator/ios/RTNCalculator-Bridging-Header.h'
  }
```

This doesn't work. I get this error in the project.

```
Using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

How do I use Swift in a Turbo Module?

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you shouldn't need a bridging header at all. That allows you to import ObjC into Swift, not Swift into ObjC. Did you try just removing the `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER` bit?

The `RTNCalculator-Swift.h` header is what lets you import Swift into ObjC, and that part of of your code looks ok. What specific error do you receive if you take out the bridging header?

Comment: If I try that I'm getting this error. It goes away if I delete the Swift file. `RTNCalculatorSpec.h:15:2 This file must be compiled as Obj-C++. If you are importing it, you must change your file extension to .mm.`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue for your Cocoa Pod (Turbo Module) you should make the following:

1. Mark `@objc` and `public` all needed classes, method, properties etc. in your swift code because all of them are `internal` by default and are not visible outside.

```swift
@objc
public class SwiftCalculator: NSObject {
    @objc
    public func add(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        a + b
    }
}
```

2. Import the pod's swift/objc generated header into your obj files in the format: "<MyPodName>+Swift.h". In your case the pod name is "rtn_calculator".

```
...
#import "rtn_calculator-Swift.h"
...
RCT_REMAP_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(add, NSNumber*, addA:(NSInteger)a andB:(NSInteger)b)
{
    SwiftCalculator* calculator = [SwiftCalculator new];
    double value = [calculator addWithA:a b:b];
    return @(value);
}
```

Comment: The header file seems to be picked up but it's not finding my Swift class. `Unknown type name 'SwiftCalculator'; did you mean 'RTNCalculator'?`

Comment: @BerryBlue The Header file name must contain the name of your pod in a podspec file: s.name = "rtn-calculator" and a name of your class must be the same.

Comment: Yes, the name is "rtn-calculator".

Comment: How do I check that it's generating the header properly?

Comment: I'm also getting this error about my Swift file so I think I still need to add a configuration somewhere. `RTNCalculatorSpec.h:15:2 This file must be compiled as Obj-C++. If you are importing it, you must change your file extension to .mm.`